# Texmaker: toggle between documents keyboard shortcut

Tags: texmaker, editors

I like this nice feature on texmaker `Options->Define Current document as 'Master Document'` and find myself using it heavily since I have my bibliography on a different file.

It would be great to switch using a keyboard shortcut. Is there any way to make it happen? 'Coz it's not shown under current shortcuts list.

EDIT: well currently you can do this by using `CTRL + SHIFT + F2` but it's very inconvenient using this combo

Answer (score 11):

I use currently Texmarker 4.2.
If I want to switch between opened documents I need to use Alt+PgUp combination buttons.

You can change it.

Preferences -> Configurations -> Shortcuts

and then you have to find what you want from the list.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im using texmaker 4.1 and I can traverse documents by Alt+PgUp or Alt+PgDown. but the functionality of that that ctrl+shift+2 are quite different where first one allows you to traverse the list while the second is toggling between just 2 documents.